# How to combine two sums and factor out a common element expression?

Tags: maxima

Here's the initial premise: two sums s1 and s2 are added; the sum element expressions have a common factor `a[n]`.

```
s1: sum(r1[m,q]*b[m,n]*a[n],n,0,N)$
s2: sum(r2[m,q]*c[m,n]*a[n],n,0,N)$
s1+s2;
```

I expect the sums to be combined and the common element expression `a[n]` factored out:

```
s12: sum(a[n]*(r1[m,q]*b[m,n]+r2[m,q]*c[m,n]),n,0,N);
```

However, I'm unable to make Maxima produce such contraction. The most simplification I was able to obtain was using `sumcontract(s1+s2)` and it results in two sums without the common element being factored out:

```
r1[m,q]*sum(b[m,n]*a[n], n,0,N) + r2[m,q]*sum(c[m,n]*a[n], n,0,N);
```

How to make Maxima produce the factored out expression from `s1+s2` as in `s12` above?

NOTE: If we remove the `r1` and `r2`, then the `factor(sumcontract(s1+s2))` indeed results in the expected `s12` expression. However, with both present, it results in two sums and does not factor out the `a[n]` as mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, let's see. Try `factor(foo)` where `foo` is the result of `sumcontract`.

Comment: Indeed! I guess, I oversimplified the example. In my actual case there are more details in the sum element expression. Looks like the part that messes with `factor()` is additional factors that do not depend on the sum's index, say `r1[m,q]` and `r2[m,q]` resp. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. I've applied `sumcontract`, `intosum`, and `factor`.

```
(%i1) s1: sum(r1[m,q]*b[m,n]*a[n],n,0,N)$

(%i2) s2: sum(r2[m,q]*c[m,n]*a[n],n,0,N)$

(%i3) s1 + s2;
                  N                       N
                 ====                    ====
                 \                       \
(%o3)     r2      >    c     a  + r1      >    b     a
            m, q /      m, n  n     m, q /      m, n  n
                 ====                    ====
                 n = 0                   n = 0
(%i4) intosum (%);
           N                       N
          ====                    ====
          \                       \
(%o4)      >    c     r2     a  +  >    b     r1     a
          /      m, n   m, q  n   /      m, n   m, q  n
          ====                    ====
          n = 0                   n = 0
(%i5) sumcontract (%);
             N
            ====
            \
(%o5)        >    (c     r2     a  + b     r1     a )
            /       m, n   m, q  n    m, n   m, q  n
            ====
            n = 0
(%i6) factor (%);
              N
             ====
             \
(%o6)         >    (c     r2     + b     r1    ) a
             /       m, n   m, q    m, n   m, q   n
             ====
             n = 0
```

In this, `intosum` is pushing constant factors back into the sum.